# Using literal month names with year in ramcharts

Tags: r, bar-chart, amcharts

Here is my code to generate barplot using rAmChart,

```
library(rAmCharts)
amBarplot(x = "month", y = "value", data = dataset, 
                  dataDateFormat = "MM/YYYY", minPeriod = "MM",
                  show_values = FALSE, labelRotation = -90, depth = 0.1)
```

However, is there a way to use month names & year in my x axis? I am trying to use MMM-YY formats.

Sample dataset,

```
 structure(list(value = c(11544, 9588, 9411, 10365, 11154, 12688
), month = c("05/2012", "06/2012", "07/2012", "08/2012", "09/2012", 
"10/2012")), .Names = c("value", "month"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the `dataset` to make the code fully reproducible

Comment: Added it here. Thanks.

Comment: storaged meant reproducible code - could you post the `dput()` of your code, so we can reproduce in R?

Comment: Indeed it would be helpful to see the `dput()` result

Comment: Added them. Hope thats fine enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that rAmCharts doesn't expose AmCharts' [`dateFormats`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#dateFormats) setting in the categoryAxis, so you have to access it through the [`init` event](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#init) and create your own `dateFormats` array with a modified format string for the `MM` period. I'm not very experienced with R, but here's how I managed to make it work using R 3.4.2 and rAmCharts 2.1.5

```
chart <- amBarplot( ... settings omitted ... )
addListener(.Object = chart,
            name = 'init',
            expression = paste(
            "function(e) {",
            "e.chart.categoryAxis.dateFormats = ", 
           '[{"period":"fff","format":"JJ:NN:SS"},{"period":"ss","format":"JJ:NN:SS"},',
           '{"period":"mm","format":"JJ:NN"},{"period":"hh","format":"JJ:NN"},{"period":"DD","format":"MMM DD"},',
           '{"period":"WW","format":"MMM DD"},',
           '{"period":"MM","format":"MMM-YY"},', # "add YY to default MM format
           '{"period":"YYYY","format":"YYYY"}]; ',
           'e.chart.validateData();',
           "}")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different solution:

```
library(rAmCharts)
dataset <-  structure(list(value = c(11544, 9588, 9411, 10365, 11154, 12688
), month = c("05/2012", "06/2012", "07/2012", "08/2012", "09/2012", 
"10/2012")), .Names = c("value", "month"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

dataset$month <- as.character(
                        format(
                           as.Date(paste0("01/",dataset$month), "%d/%m/%Y"),
                        "%B %Y"))

amBarplot(x = "month", y = "value", data = dataset, 
                  show_values = FALSE, labelRotation = -90, depth = 0.1)
```

[image]